# Deal with broken pipe problem with ssh local port forwarding

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

My server is behind a firewall that exposes only port 22. I frequently use SSH local port forwarding to access several HTTP services running on the server. It works, but not always. Now and then I get an error message `packet_write_wait: Connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Broken pipe` and I have to restart the SSH connection for it to work again.

I have `ServerAliveInterval` set to 30 in my config file. In addition, I often open multiple independent ssh processes with different ports forwarded. When one is broken, others work still, so I would think that the network connection itself should be normal.

If it is of any use, my client is on macOS High Sierra, and the server is running Ubuntu 16.04.

What could be the cause of the issue? What potential solutions could I have?

Answer (score 0):

If that is an ssh connection, then you might want to make sure you send a keepalive message to the server.